# Mysql Join Query to get multiple children

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a database with the following

```
id
parentid
```

I want to get all records based on child parent, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID='id' OR PARENTID='id' OR PARENTID='id of last one selected' etc..
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: mysql can't. write a procedure

Comment: Not much. please clarify